# Why does Pycharm highlight the unresolved reference in a file but doesn't highlight the same error in the same file in another directory?

Tags: python, pycharm

The Pycharm in my laptop highlights the undefined variables as 'unresolved reference' but doesn't do this in another file. How should I make it do this for all files? Could anyone tell me?

Actually, I just want Pycharm to show the undefined variables in my code. It is really troublesome if the editor can't detect undefined variables...

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific in describing your project setup, etc. Pycharm generally shows undefined variables and many other errors.

Answer (score 0):

To enable error checking for unresolved references, go to "Preferences."
 [Preferences Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldqa2.png)

Then, select "Editor"...
[Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myvPv.png)

Then "Inspections"...
[Inspections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkqw0.png)

Then search for "unresolved reference." 
[Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi02R.png)

Error checking for unresolved references should be enabled by default.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHcU.png)

Comment: Finally, it seems that I solved that problem by reloading a new python configuration in Pycharm. Anyway, thank you very much!